# How do I fix this error when debugging in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, swiz

I am completely new to Flex and have been given an application to work on. I am trying to debug it for the first time (first time for me) and it has run for the previous coworker (who is no longer here, so I can't ask him).
Here is the stacktrace:

```
[SWF] C:\Users\allisonc\Documents\Flex Builder 3\te\bin-debug\Works.swf - 1,175,412 bytes after decompression
[SWF] C:\Users\allisonc\Documents\Flex Builder 3\te\bin-debug\Works.swf - 1,152,031 bytes after decompression
Error: Could not get a reference to class for ImageEvent.REQUEST_LOAD_ALBUMS. Did you specify its package in SwizConfig::eventPackages?
    at org.swizframework.processors::MediateProcessor/validateMediateMetadataTag()[/Users/asstrochris/Documents/my_projects/swizframework-git/swiz-framework/src/org/swizframework/processors/MediateProcessor.as:224]
    at org.swizframework.processors::MediateProcessor/setUpMetadataTag()[/Users/asstrochris/Documents/my_projects/swizframework-git/swiz-framework/src/org/swizframework/processors/MediateProcessor.as:87]
    at org.swizframework.processors::BaseMetadataProcessor/setUpMetadataTags()[/Users/asstrochris/Documents/my_projects/swizframework-git/swiz-framework/src/org/swizframework/processors/BaseMetadataProcessor.as:115]
    at org.swizframework.core::BeanFactory/setUpBean()[/Users/asstrochris/Documents/my_projects/swizframework-git/swiz-framework/src/org/swizframework/core/BeanFactory.as:276]
    at org.swizframework.core::BeanFactory/setUpBeans()[/Users/asstrochris/Documents/my_projects/swizframework-git/swiz-framework/src/org/swizframework/core/BeanFactory.as:244]
    at org.swizframework.core::Swiz/init()[/Users/asstrochris/Documents/my_projects/swizframework-git/swiz-framework/src/org/swizframework/core/Swiz.as:313]
    at org.swizframework.core.mxml::Swiz/handleContainerPreinitialize()[/Users/asstrochris/Documents/my_projects/swizframework-git/swiz-framework/src/org/swizframework/core/mxml/Swiz.as:75]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/initialize()
    at mx.core::Container/initialize()
    at mx.core::Application/initialize()
    at Works/initialize()[C:\Users\allisonc\Documents\Flex Builder 3\te\src\Works.mxml:0]
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::childAdded()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2009]
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/initializeTopLevelWindow()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:3234]
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::docFrameHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:3064]
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/docFrameListener()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2916]
```

Here is the swizconfig

```
<swiz:Swiz  id="swiz" config="{swizConfig}" beanProviders="{[Beans]}" loggingTargets="{[]}"  />
<swiz:SwizConfig id="swizConfig"
strict="true"   
eventPackages="model.event"
viewPackages="view"/>
```

I also get an error: Source not found:

```
org.swizframework.processors::MediateProcessor/validateMediateMetadataTag
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [this tutorial](https://swizframework.jira.com/wiki/display/SWIZ/Quick+Start) This is a framework specific error. there is a config file for swiz framework, this needs to know the event classes, you mention the ImageEvent.as class path in there. hopefully it should start working.

Comment: Where is the config file?

Comment: you have to search for this tag in your workspace <swiz:config> this has the config information.

Comment: You should be able to find the ImageEvent in the model.event package, if not you have to move it there or add it to the config as mentioned in this tutorial.  https://swizframework.jira.com/wiki/display/SWIZ/Quick+Start

Comment: I found the ImageEvent where you said it was.

Comment: Since you are saying that it is in model.event folder, then it could be possible that the compilation has not happened properly. You can try to clean the project by selecting the Project > clean (select all the works paces that are related to flex, i'm hoping the setup is all good.)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swiz-framework/LMMqJRnMDTw this has similar issue.

Comment: What do you mean by the "compilation has not happened properly" - how do I do that?

Comment: You can try to clean the project by selecting the Project > clean

Comment: I did the clean, still getting the error. I added more code in the question.

Comment: Did you check this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swiz-framework/LMMqJRnMDTw

Comment: Yes, but I am only using one package (model.event)